# How to render out errors on forms using form_for with multiple nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form here for adding new transactions. I understand that the below is a little bit messy with all the nested resources, but it works for now whilst I'm still learning Rails.

```
<%= form_for([@company, @captable, @event, @transaction]) do |f| %>
  <% if @transaction.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@transaction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this transaction from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I have the following check in my `transactions_controller.rb` which works perfectly. If the condition is true, the script stops running and I am successfully redirected back to the new form. However, I cannot seem to get the error to display. To clarify: everything works as expected, except the rendering of the error message in the form above.

```
# Verify that the transaction is valid first before saving 
@selling_shareholder = Shareholder.find(params[:selling_shareholder_id])
if @transaction.number_of_stocks > @selling_shareholder.number_of_stocks #Seller cannot sell more stocks then they own 
    @transaction.errors.add(:number_of_stocks, "Seller cannot sell more stocks then they own")
    redirect_to new_company_captable_event_transaction_path
    return
end
```

Would love some help on how to successfully render out errors to these forms with multiple nested models. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, the idiomatic solution to working with nested resources is using either `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or using a pattern called [form objects](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects) which are then responsible for translating the input into your ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Thank you! Will read up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `redirect_to new_company_captable_event_transaction_path` which initializes a **new request** to the server, so the form errors are lost. You should use `render` instead of `redirect_to`

```
# Verify that the transaction is valid first before saving 
@selling_shareholder = Shareholder.find(params[:selling_shareholder_id])
if @transaction.number_of_stocks > @selling_shareholder.number_of_stocks #Seller cannot sell more stocks then they own 
  @transaction.errors.add(:number_of_stocks, "Seller cannot sell more stocks then they own")
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I got a DoubleRenderError because further down in the create method I have another redirect. Is it possible to combine your solution above but also stop the script at that point so we don't get a DoubleRenderError?

For example, could I use 

`render 'new' 
 return` 

as to stop any other code in the controller from running?

Comment: @JP89 Try to change that `redirect_to` to like this `redirect_to return`. Just like you have it in the question